# Linear Function For Primes

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $f:Z \to F_p$ be a function with p>3, p being a prime. F has the following property:

$$f(\alpha+\beta)+f(\alpha+2\beta)+f(\alpha+3\beta)=0 $$for$$ \alpha∈Z, \beta∈Z+. $$

Prove f(n) = 0 for all $n \in Z$.

Is $F_p$ simply the field of prime numbers or the quotient ring? since field of the quotient ring have to be bigger or equal to 0, then the result is trivial for f(n)=0? am i missing something?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the quotient ring".  I'd assume that $F_p$ was intended to refer to the field with $p$ elements.

Comment: like Z/pZ ring sorry, and what does field with p elements mean exactly? they can be any pe elements

Comment: Well, $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is a field.  That's what one means by "the field with $p$ elements".

Comment: Also...your header describes $f$ as "linear", which would normally imply that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.  You also  tag "linear algebra" and "vector spaces".  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

*(I assume that $F_p$ is the field with $p$ elements, aka $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$)*

Fix $\beta=1$:

$\alpha=0 \implies f(1)+f(2)+f(3)=0$

$\alpha=1 \implies f(2)+f(3)+f(4)=0 \implies f(1)=f(4)$

$\alpha=2 \implies f(3)+f(4)+f(5)=0 \implies f(2)=f(5)$

$\alpha=3 \implies f(4)+f(5)+f(6)=0 \implies f(3)=f(6)$

In general, $f(n)=f(n \bmod 3)$.

Fix $\beta=3$:

$\alpha=0 \implies f(3)+f(6)+f(9)=0 \ \ \implies 3f(3)=0 \implies f(3)=0$

$\alpha=1 \implies f(4)+f(7)+f(10)=0 \implies 3f(4)=0 \implies f(4)=0$

$\alpha=2 \implies f(5)+f(8)+f(11)=0 \implies 3f(5)=0 \implies f(5)=0$

Thus, $f(n)=f(n \bmod 3)=0$.

Comment: So it is enough to take the codomain to be $\mathbb Z_m$ with $\gcd(3,m)=1$.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by your comment? how does showing mod 3 show the rest?

Comment: @jamesblack, apart from the comment, do you understand the answer and the role of $p$ being prime greater than $3$?